# 殊: Why 歺(歹)+朱? How did it get to mean special (in a good way)?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

How did 殊, as in: 特殊、殊技、殊荣、殊勋、殊遇、殊遇 come to have it's meaning of `special`?

歺(歹)+朱 paint out a rather, more, grim meaning if anything...

- *說文解字*:

> 死也。从歺朱聲。漢令曰：“蠻夷長有罪，當殊之。”市朱切

How did 殊 get to mean special (in a good way)?

Comment: FYI: The original meaning of「殊」has shifted to「誅」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any reference on it, so I come out with my own ideas.

[**Phonetic loan**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_.28phonetic_loan.29_characters). In the beginning the ancestors created the character 殊, but the same sound also means "special" to them. The ancestors are as lazy as us, so instead of creating a new character, they borrowed the character 殊 to fill the blank. This is not as likely as my next speculation.

**Amelioration**, a form of [semantic change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change) in which a word's meaning is changed from bad to good:

- Originally `殊` means `to put to death`, which is an `extreme` measure, hence `very` and `overly`.
- `殊` puts life to death, hence `different`.
- If it gets to "very" and "different", there is no way to prevent it to mean `special`.

This, I think, is probably the case. For comparison, the English word `dead` could also mean `very`, `completely`, or `exactly`, all positive meanings.

Answer (score 0):

[殊 Kanji Etymology 日本語の漢字語源・由来 - Brad Warden](https://bradwarden.com/kanji/etymology/?%E6%AE%8A)

> As per [朱](https://bradwarden.com/kanji/etymology/?%E6%9C%B1)# (stump) + [歹](https://bradwarden.com/kanji/etymology/?%E6%AD%B9) severed bone/death → sever limbs, leaving only stumpy remains → *special*; *characteristic* (← special type of punishment).

Comment: That site is not very good - everything seems to be treated as a compound ideogram. The author doesn’t seem to know about sound components very well or at all.

Comment: @dROOOze Are you referring to phonosemantic compounds (形聲字)? I know 形聲字 can split into 意符 and 聲符 some times, but not always! 聲符  can affect the first 意符, and be a second 意符. My teachers told me that the 聲符 can be semantic too!  The 聲符 can play a semantic role too, and affect the meaning of the 形聲字. Most Chinese do not know if a word is a 形聲字. Even if they know a word is a 形聲字, they will not know which is 意符 and  聲符. So it is expected that  聲符 is phonetic AND semantic. Make sense?

Comment: The stack exchanges generally pursue correctness and rigour of information, not "what Chinese people know" or what a random teacher said. We do not care how many native speakers think they know. `聲符 can be semantic too` requires hard, traceable evidence in excavated and received texts, something I highly doubt your teacher has any knowledge about.

Comment: I am confused....so you are arguing that 聲符 are NEVER semantic, and ONLY phonetic? That  形聲字 can ALWAYS split and clear cut into 意符 and 聲符?

Comment: I didn't say that. When 聲符 plays a semantic role it is traced through historical examples or careful analysis. For example, 采 in 採 is both semantic and phonetic, while 唯 in 雖 is not. However, when in doubt, it is *not* both semantic and phonetic, because if everything is semantic then anything can mean anything else and the idea of a semantic component completely loses any significance.

Comment: I still confused.... For any 形聲字, how do we know if 聲符 plays a semantic role, and is a 意符 too?